# Real Time Routes. No route matches in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, routes, rack

I'm in over my head and can't figure a way out. Any help or direction would be great. Thank you.

I have a catchall route that works in real life but fails in respec. If I hardcode in a test route it passes my tests.

**Base Code**

routes.rb

```
class SEORoutes
  def call(env) 
    # some logic is sorted here to figure out controller/action but results in below
     controller = 'big_monkey_controller' 
     controller_class = controller.camelize.constantize
     binding.pry
     controller_class.action("show".to_sym).call(env)
  end
end

match "*stuff/:id", to: SEORoutes.new, via: :all
```

**Failing Test Results: Requests**

rspec results of failed test

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
  No route matches {:stuff=>"ice-cream", :id=>"yum"}
```

The message happens in my requests specs on the following line

```
visit "/ice-cream/yum"
```

**Step Through**

So I step through with the binding.pry that's in the code above.

controller_class seems okay

```
[1]pry(#<SEORoutes> controller_class
=> BigMonkeyController
```

controller_class.action seems okay

```
[2] pry(#<SEORoutes>)> controller_class.action("show".to_sym)
=> #<Proc:0xb9c0114c@/home/haley/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:230>
```

call(env) seems to be the problem. Same error as in rspec

```
[3] pry(#<SEORoutes>)> controller_class.action("show".to_sym).call(env)
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:stuff=>"ice-cream", :id=>"yum"} from /home/haley/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:39:in `generate'
```

So this is where I'm in over my head. It seems like rspec handles Rack/call(env) differently than development or even production but I'm not sure.

**What to do?**

If this is the case what do I do to have `call(env)` behave the same in rspec. Or is it something else? Or is there a better testing approach?

I have been unable to find anything on this topic which points to a solution so any guidance would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Is this a controller spec?

Comment: Hi @zetetic, it's a requests spec. Error happens on `visit "/ice-cream/yum"` I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Am I reading this correctly that 'match "*stuff/:id"' should match "blahblahstuff/1", "yadayadastuff/2" etc?  Basically the tail end of the match is "stuff/:id" so I would expect your rspec to visit a path with "stuff" in the url... "visit "ice-creamstuff/yum"...

Comment: Hey @MichaelLang actually "*stuff" sets the params key. so the url is "/ice-cream/yum" but `params[:stuff] = "ice-cream"` and `params[:id] = "yum"`. There's a better explanation in [Rails Routes Globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments).

Comment: @haley Ah, you're right -- 'twas before my morning coffee and I wasn't thinking clearly when I read through the code first time.